# how to use ng-disabled along with div in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

> ng-disabled="condition" not disabling the div even when the condition is true.

---

```
<div ng-disabled="true">
// display something
</div>
```

Comment: what is your expectation for a disabled div that isn't editable? Please provide all relevant code and expected behaviors. I don't think a div can even be disabled

Comment: semantic way of using ng-disabled is for form elements not to div. Refer this https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html

Comment: @Venkatraman thank for the update. Got the way to disable it through ng-class.  Thanks.

Comment: Check my answer. if you want to know real usage about ng-disabled directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="true">
// display something
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks.  It works. Even i got another way using ng-class.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: You can use `ng-show / ng-hide` directive for DIV elements to show or hide !

Use for `Form Elements` for appropriate usage of `ng-disabled` directive. see below code snippet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
 <label>Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"></label><br/>
 <button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="checked">Button</button>
</div>
```

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled
What to disable: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html

> Below elements can be disabled.

1. button
2. input
3. select
4. textarea
5. optgroup
6. option
7. fieldset